# How to allow only mui colors as prop for other components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am customizing the MUI theme for my app.

I have some icons that expose the `fill` and `stroke` colors so that I can customize them from outside when using the component itself, and it looks like this:

```
interface IconProps {
  width?: string;
  height?: string;
  fill?: string;
  stroke?: string;
  className?: string;
  onClick?: (e?: unknown) => void;
}


export const LogoutIcon = ({
  width = '100%',
  height = '100%',
  fill = 'white',
  stroke = 'black',
  className = 'customIcon',
}: IconProps) => {
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={width}
      height={height}
      fill={fill}
      stroke={stroke}
      className={className}
      id="lvl_2"
      viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    >
      <path
        d="m9 12 3-3m0 0L9 6m3 3H1m5-4.751V4.2c0-1.12 0-1.68.218-2.108.192-.377.497-.682.874-.874C7.52 1 8.08 1 9.2 1h4.6c1.12 0 1.68 0 2.107.218.377.192.683.497.875.874.218.427.218.987.218 2.105v9.607c0 1.117 0 1.676-.218 2.104a2.002 2.002 0 0 1-.875.874c-.427.218-.986.218-2.104.218H9.197c-1.118 0-1.678 0-2.105-.218a2 2 0 0 1-.874-.874C6 15.48 6 14.92 6 13.8v-.05"
        stroke={stroke}
        stroke-width="2"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

This works fine, but now that I have implemented the theme correctly and I am using only colors from Material theme itself, I'd like to change the props so that only Material ui colors are accepted as `fill` and `stroke` values.

I have tried with no luck to change it like this:

```
import { PaletteColor } from '@mui/material'
import { PaletteOptions } from '@mui/material'
import { useThemeContext } from '../../providers/hooks'


type IconProps = {
  width?: string
  height?: string
  fill?: keyof PaletteOptions
  stroke?: keyof PaletteOptions
  className?: string
  onClick?: (e?: unknown) => void
}

export const LogoutIcon = ({
  width = '100%',
  height = '100%',
  fill,
  stroke,
  className = 'customIcon',
}: IconProps) => {
  const theme = useThemeContext()
  const iconFill = theme.palette[fill] || 'background'
  const iconStroke = theme.palette[stroke] || 'text'
  return (
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width={width}
      height={height}
      fill={iconFill}
      stroke={iconStroke}
      className={className}
      id="Livello_2"
      viewBox="0 0 18 18"
    >
      <path
        d="m9 12 3-3m0 0L9 6m3 3H1m5-4.751V4.2c0-1.12 0-1.68.218-2.108.192-.377.497-.682.874-.874C7.52 1 8.08 1 9.2 1h4.6c1.12 0 1.68 0 2.107.218.377.192.683.497.875.874.218.427.218.987.218 2.105v9.607c0 1.117 0 1.676-.218 2.104a2.002 2.002 0 0 1-.875.874c-.427.218-.986.218-2.104.218H9.197c-1.118 0-1.678 0-2.105-.218a2 2 0 0 1-.874-.874C6 15.48 6 14.92 6 13.8v-.05"
        stroke={iconStroke}
        stroke-width="2"
        stroke-linecap="round"
        stroke-linejoin="round"
      />
    </svg>
  )
}
```

*(the hook `useThemeContext` is out of scope for this, it basically returns the theme with all the theme properties)*

By doing this I was hoping to be able to pass as prop for the icon **only** material ui palette keys but it is not working and I have this error here:

[image]

What should I do to fix this?

Also, I have another question (which is more of a curiosity):

Since the interface for the palette material theme looks like this:

```
export type PaletteColorOptions = SimplePaletteColorOptions | ColorPartial;

export interface SimplePaletteColorOptions {
  light?: string;
  main: string;
  dark?: string;
  contrastText?: string;
}
```

How can I extend the requirement above so that I can pass something like:

`stroke={'text.main'}` or `stroke={'text.dark'}` ?

I have tried using this syntax on the native material buttons but it seems like only main palette keys are accepted, is this correct or Am I looking at something wrong?

Thanks a lot